# Is there an established way to quantify the number of parameters in a random forest?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, random-forest, nonparametric, degrees-of-freedom, f-test

I'm interested in applying an F-test to random forest regression models I've trained. The formula for calculating an F-statistic (found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test) requires values for $p_1$ and $p_2$, where $p_2$ is the number of parameters of the unrestricted (random forest) model. I know this is pretty unconventional, but I was just wondering if anyone has suggestions as to how I could quantify $p_2$ rigorously given the nonparametric nature of random forest methods.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem where you have problem X and try to solve it with some solution, but you don’t fully understand your solution, either, so you ask about your proposed solution instead of your original problem. (This is extremely common on here.) Do you have some question X that you want to solve?

Comment: In short -- forget the F test and talk about the issue you're trying to use an F test to address. (I could give you a way to count parameters, but it would be of no use since your F test would not have an F-distribution.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think a good description of my goal comes from the wikipedia article: "One common context in this regard is that of deciding whether a model fits the data significantly better than does a naive model, in which the only explanatory term is the intercept term, so that all predicted values for the dependent variable are set equal to that variable's sample mean." Is there a more appropriate way to approach this?

Comment: This [arXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.00190) discusses effective degrees of freedom for random forests!

Comment: Thanks @kjetilbhalvorsen!